child_process : exec is not a function
I try to execute a PowerShell command with child_process but when I execute the command I receive: exec is not a function
Here is my code :
const { exec } = require('child_process');

export default function boostFps() {
    // PowerShell command to run with elevated privileges
    const command = 'powershell -Command "& {Set-ItemProperty -Path \'HKLM:\\SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows NT\\CurrentVersion\\Multimedia\\SystemProfile\' -Name SystemResponsiveness -Value 0}"';

    exec(command, (err, stdout, stderr) => {
        if (err) {
            console.error(err);
            return;
        }
        console.log(stdout);
    });
}

trying to execute a PowerShell command to boost fps

Is this running in a browser?

Please share how this code is executed.
